# Android: Using Opengles to draw on a 320x240 screen, the 1080p picture preview will have moire?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Android uses Opengles to draw a 1080 screen on a 320x240 screen, and the preview will have moiré. Is there any way to solve it. Setting GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER has no effect.

```
    public static int createCameraTexture() {
    int[] texture = new int[1];
    GLES30.glGenTextures(1, texture, 0);
    GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture[0]);
    GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
    return texture[0];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using some form of multisampling as stated at?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386807/c-removing-moire-effect-from-opengl

Comment: Where do you generate the mipmaps? ([`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml))